# Progress Bar with countdown timer in android

Tags: android-layout

I need a progress bar in my layout, which will have a total time of 30 secs and will tick every second. Basically I want the user of my app to see that he has 30 sec time before time is up.

This is the piece of code I have written.
But this gives me a blank progress bar with no activity. Please help.
What am I doing wrong

```
public class MySeekBarActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);      

    final ProgressBar progressHorizontal = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_horizontal);
    progressHorizontal.setProgress(progressHorizontal.getProgress()* 100);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {              
            progressHorizontal.incrementProgressBy(1);
            int dtotal = (int) ( 30000 - millisUntilFinished ) /30000 * 100;
            progressHorizontal.setProgress(dtotal);                
        }            
        public void onFinish() {
            // DO something when 2 minutes is up
       }
   }.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a type conversion bug, due to two things:

- you're dividing by an int, which causes the decimal to be rounded down,
- also, you're casting the result too early, so even if you'd divide by a float/double, the result would get rounded down anyway.

To see what I mean - you can safely remove the cast to int from your code, and it will compile anyway. That means your final number is an int, and since you're not making any casts earlier, it means you're losing the decimal info pretty early on in the code.

This is a possible fix:

```
int dtotal = (int) (( 30000 - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)30000 * 100);
```

to resolve such bugs in the future, **make a dummy Java program with a loop containing the equation, and print out the intermediate result, for example:**

```
public class NumberTester {

    //define the constants in your loop
    static final int TOTAL_TIME = 30000;
    static final int INTERVAL = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //perform the loop
        for(int millisUntilFinished = TOTAL_TIME;millisUntilFinished >=0;millisUntilFinished -= INTERVAL) {
            int dtotal = (int) (( TOTAL_TIME - millisUntilFinished ) /(double)TOTAL_TIME * 100);
            System.out.println(dtotal);
        }

    }

}
```

Also, some important things:

- don't start your timer in *onCreate* - your activity is not visible yet at this point! Use *onResume* instead.
- kill your timer in *onPause*. Leaving timers and threads unmanaged like that is bad form, and may lead to weird bugs.
- don't use ["magic numbers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). Place all your constant values in a static final class members, like I've done in the example. This will save you a lot of headaches when you decide to change those values.

**EDIT:** as to why your progress bar stops short of completion, that's because the *onTick* method works a bit differently than you're probably assuming it does. To see what I mean, add:

```
System.out.println("Milis:" + millisUntilFinished);
System.out.println("dtotal:" + dtotal);
```

to your *onTick* method. The values clearly don't count down to 0 (and hence 100 in the case of dtotal, it being derived from millisUntilFinished) - you have to compensate for that.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But the progress bar is stopping short of one tick. i.e in the end thr is one slot left.

Comment: Thanks again. But my progress bar is stopping short of one tick, ie thr is one slot left in the end, can you please tell me wats the problem ?

Comment: I've edited the answer with the explanation of why that happens. See the bottom of the post.

Comment: dtotal = 0, 10 , 20, 30, 40, 51,61, 71, 82

Comment: and what about the values for the miliseconds?

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste those: here they are
9977, 8962, 7958, 6944, 5903, 4866, 3832, 2804, 1771. As of now, i am using total time as 10 seconds instead of 30sec

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough - I'm asking these questions because I know what the values are, but I'd like to figure out the solution by yourself :). Anyway, as you see the final value 1771, which is quite far away from 0. Do you understand now why the progress bar never becomes completely full?